# SUMIFS Multiple Criteria with Date Range Criteria

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a data set like this (not table):

[image]

I want to Sum with following criteria: US, Apple and date prior to today.
Because of the data layout the SUMIFS formula doesn't seems to work.

This is what I have:
`=SUMIFS(C2:G3,A2:A3,"US",B2:B3,"Apple",A3:G3,"<"&Today())`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SUMIFS requires all the ranges to be the same size and shape.  you will want SUMPRODUCT:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(C2:G3*(A2:A3="US")*(B2:B3="Apple")*($C$1:$G$1<Today()))
```

Comment: Is this array formula? I have to ctrl shift enter right?

Comment: @user12224011 It is an array formula but it is native and as such does NOT need the CSE entry.

Comment: `C2:G3,` didn't work, so I changed it to `C2:G3*` changed comma to star *  
I'm using excel 2016. Thank you!

Comment: @user12224011 yes sorry, `,` only works when the ranges are the same size and shape.  Sorry.

Comment: I'm keep getting an error "There is a problem with this formula"...

Comment: Figured it out, I removed `"<"&` quotation and & from the formula so just `range<Today()` worked

Comment: @user12224011 that is what I get for trying to answer from my phone with copy paste.